# Vertical drop down menu hover effect to close sub menu when hover out

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I have this menu that I need to tweak a bit because its not very user friendly. When you see the demo you can notice that the hover effect triggers on 1st hover and stays open till hover again on  (Resturant). I want to make it when the pointer goes out of the link box to close automatically. Also when I hover in and out again and again and fast then there is like 15 seconds of animations. Can I some how tweak that?

here is a demo, note that its still work in progress.

[LINK](http://tinyurl.com/otwocvz)

and this is the javascript I have for this menu.

```
        ( function( $ ) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').mouseenter(function( event ){
            $(this).removeAttr('href');
            var element = $(this).parent('li');
            if (element.hasClass('open')) {
                element.removeClass('open');
                element.find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.find('ul').slideUp();
            }
            else {
                element.addClass('open');
                element.children('ul').slideDown();
                element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
                element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
                element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
            }
        });

        $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

        (function getColor() {
            var r, g, b;
            var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
            textColor = textColor.slice(4);
            r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
            textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
            textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
            var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
            if (l > 0.7) {
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 0px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
                $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
            }
        })();

        function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
            r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
            var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
            var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

            if(max == min){
                h = s = 0;
            }
            else {
                var d = max - min;
                s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
                switch(max){
                    case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
                    case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
                    case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
                }
                h /= 6;
            }
            return l;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    } )( jQuery );
```

Comment: next time it would be better to add an jsfiddle...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e5n80zxv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thath becouse the function run only on 'mouseenter' event if you use 'hover' instead the function will fire on 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave' :D

Replace

```
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').mouseenter(function( event ){
```

with

```
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').hover(function( event ){
```

about the delay: jquery will save the animation for each event fired to stop immediately all the other animations on the element you must add:

```
.stop( true, true )
```

**JSFIDDLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/m90s2dq5/2/

**JSFIDDLE** (CSS solution) : http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/m90s2dq5/3/

Comment: Hi, I did that what you suggested it did the work perfectly but now I cant use the sub menu you can check the url again

Comment: How about css only solution?

Comment: Ok i fixed js... i will post that 2 solutions :D

Comment: Great thanks to you now i will read and find the changes and see what I was missing :)

Comment: I can explain later :D if you will... just let me know if you need more explaination here in comments

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `.mouseleave()` or `.hover()` Function.
For example:

```
$('#cssmenu .has-subs').hover(function() {
   //do something when mouse enters
}, function() {
   //do something when mouse leaves
});
```

Check out http://api.jquery.com/hover/ to learn more.

Hope this helps.